# D3 - can you pass a string to function to use as key?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data is in a csv file and looks like the following:

```
year,rs,team,ra,ws,finals
2002,892,bears,676,no,no
2003,873,bears,702,no,yes
2004,899,bears,815,no,yes
2005,828,bears,748,no,no
...
```

Initially, all I was concerned with was graphing the rs variable values and the code was very straightforward since I could just refer directly to rs, for example:

```
graph() {
    ...
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.rs = +d.rs;
    });

    y.domain([500,d3.max(data.map(function(d) {return d.rs;}))]); 
    ...
}
```

However, to make the graph more interactive, I am using radio buttons to allow the user to choose which variable to chart. In the onClick handler, I am passing the name of the variable in my dataset to graph, e.g. `onclick="graph('ra')"` or `onclick="graph('rs')"`.  However, is there a way to pass in the string and have the code "substitute" the string as the variable.  I tried doing something like the following, which doesn't work:

```
graph(variable_to_graph) {
    ...
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.variable_to_graph = +d.variable_to_graph;
    });

    y.domain([500,d3.max(data.map(function(d) {return d.variable_to_graph;}))]); 
    ...
}
```

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and d3, but my intuition is that this should be doable.  I would also like to put in a text field and allow the user to enter a custom mathematical expression (e.g. `rs/ra` or `(rs*2)/ (ra^2)`) and somehow graph those results by passing in the expression as a string, e.g. `graph("(rs*2)/ (ra^2)")`.  I have no idea where to begin with that and whether it is even possible.  The ideal solution would be able to accommodate both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a property name using a variable that holds the property name, you use `object[propName]` like this:

```
d[variable_to_graph]
```

Or in your function:

```
graph(variable_to_graph) {
    ...
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = +d.year;
        d[variable_to_graph] = +d[variable_to_graph];
    });

    y.domain([500,d3.max(data.map(function(d) {return d[variable_to_graph];}))]); 
    ...
}
```